# UAC dialog for an installer with a manifest and code signed

Tags: c++, certificate, manifest, uac, signtool

I wrote a setup.exe installer in C++ that has to be released through a web server. I attached a manifest with 'requestAdministrator' elevation and i signed it with a regular code certificate bought by Verisign. In a machine with windows 7 with UAC enabled if i download the file through internet Explorer 10 and choose to 'Run' the file immediately, after the download, UAC prompts a dialog with yellow shield on yellow background telling me that the executable comes from an untrusted source and requiring a confirmation for its execution. Additional informations are the name of the file 'setup.exe' and the origin 'Downloaded from the internet' and nothing else. Why the publisher doesn't appear?. If i choose 'Save and run' instead, UAC prompts correctly a blue shield, with program name, the name of my company in the 'Verified publisher' field and file origin 'Downloaded from the internet'. I'm not disappointed for the difference between the levels of warning of the two dialogs but above all for the lack of the publisher name in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to digitally sign your application.

**Before digitally signing:**

[image]

**After digitally signing:**

[image]

Yes, it means you'll have to spend $200 a year for a digital signing certificate from someplace. It's a scam. i know.

But that's the answer.